# How to use gcs emulator as apache beam pipeline's temp_location?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam-io, google-cloud-storage

Because of corporate policy, I don't have access to bucket in SIT environment from my PC.
When I run dataflow locally, and read/write to BigQuery, pipeline needs temp_location to store temp files.

I run oittaa/gcp-storage-emulator locally in container. Usually I access default bucket using url like http://localhost:8080/<emulator_bucket>.

But in pipeline options, I need to configure temp_location as gs://<emulator_bucket>.

How can I configure pipeline options to use emulator bucket?

I've tried:

1. Env var STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST="http://localhost:8080"
   And use gs://<emulator_bucket>
2. Use url instead of gs://

Both don't work. Approach 1, pipeline still trying to connect to https://storage.cloud.google.com. Approach 2, just throw error, didn't recognize the config value.

Comment: what is the error that you are seeing in approach 2?

Comment: I got exception:
Unable to get filesystem from specified path, please use the correct path or ensure the required dependency is installed, e.g., pip install apache-beam[gcp]. Path specified: http://localhost:8080/defaultbucket [while running 'Read all timestamp of existing records

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/) the Google Cloud Dataflow Runner uses the Cloud Dataflow managed service. When you run your pipeline with the Cloud Dataflow service, the runner uploads your executable code and dependencies to a Google Cloud Storage bucket and creates a Cloud Dataflow job, which executes your pipeline on managed resources in Google Cloud Platform.

```
temp_location : Must be a valid Google Cloud Storage URL that begins with gs://
```

Instead of giving invalid url you must need to use a valid Google Cloud Storage URL.You are facing the error message due to the invalid url.Your organization can give you  [least privileges](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#accessing_gcs) and [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control)  to access cloud storage  buckets.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's the reason, question is how could I make the local emulator's url a valid google cloud storage url that pipeline recognizes? Running pipeline locally to write to BQ has to use a real bucket? (emulator bucket can't be used)?

Comment: Hi @Ken,according to this [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/) temp_location location url must be begins with `gs://` so based on my understanding you have to use a real cloud storage url.